PWMs from microcontroller are resetting
I have been designing an SMPS where the STM32F334R8t6 microcontroller provides the full bridge control signals. The microcontroller board uses a 5 V and 3 V regulator to supply the MCU and the CAN transceiver. However, the microcontroller has been showing irregular behavior since the board was brought up and I have ignored it while working on the firmware.
Now, I am unsure where to start looking as I am fairly new to embedded systems. The irregularities that I have noticed are:

Break at address (seems to be system memory addresses) when starting a Debug Session on Stm32CubeIDE

Receives SGNL Interrupts between breakpoints

Gate signals appear to start and restart



Output Voltage of 5V Regulator

Microcontroller board

Schematics



PCB


Why is the waveform drooping off? Please post a schematic.

Is there a decoupling capacitor close to the power pins of the microcontroller?

"Output Voltage of 5V Regulator" Err.... wth is that? Either your measurement is bananas, or your regulator is. In case of the regular, maybe it goes into overcurrent or thermal shutdown, maybe you haven't picked the right caps or the load is wrong etc etc. Schematics are necessary to troubleshoot. Though more likely you are using some strange setting on the scope.

Yes, there are decoupling capacitors close to the power pins of the microcontroller. I have added the schematics on the post for reference and don't think the scope settings are wrong. The board was hand-soldered with a heat gun, are there chances that the microcontroller is damaged or is it unlikely?

I assume this little 9 V battery on the photo cannot feed the circuit.
